# Full height sidebar and full height content, fluid layout

Tags: css, css-float

[Possible duplicate didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922755/html-css-full-height-sidebar)

I know there are many answers about this topic but neither of them helped me and I spent days on
this problem.
90% of the answers and books give this background trick which didn't help me.

[My code - Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PeGGQJ?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<body >
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ANALYTICS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">STYLES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VOTERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GET STARTED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">UPDATE</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.content {
  width: 95%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  background: url(http://s9.postimg.org/ft91z9c6z/bg_content.png) repeat-y left top;
}

.sidebar{
  width: 5%;
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: url(http://s21.postimg.org/kexv3aupf/bg_sidebar.png) repeat-y left top;

}

.sidebar ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;

}

.sidebar li{
     padding: 50%;
     position: relative;
}

.sidebar a{
        display: block;
        font-size: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
}
```

**Right now my layout looks like this:**

[image: Right now my layout looks like this:]

**And I want it to look like this:**

[image]

I followed this [guide](http://line25.com/articles/create-sidebars-of-equal-height-with-faux-columns) offered in the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922755/html-css-full-height-sidebar) and it didn't help
I think this is because I'm using `floats` and `fluid layout`.

How can I extend the columns while keeping the `fluid layout` and the `float` positioning.

Comment: Have you tried the search functionality in the site? There are thousands of questions like that, all of them answered with a good solution.

Comment: I spent 2 days already and all the answers didn't help me, and most of them are meant for fixed layouts, I even read abook on this topic "CSS the missing manual" 90% of the answers give the same solution using this background trick which does not work, for me at least.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've updated your code. Check out it on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1vTAqeZvst7WEE8j1gv?p=preview).

At first try to not use `absolute` or `relative` positions, if there is no need of them.

The second, in your case by giving `display: inline` and `float: left` styles, do the same thing, so there is enough to use only the latter one.

Besides, I've set the `height` of `HTML` and `BODY` tags to be 100% and did the same for `sidebar` and `content` `DIV`s, so they will `fill` the `parent`'s (`body`) height.

And finally, one of your problems was the `repeat-y` value of `background` property. It didn't repeat on x axis, so you didn't see the actual size of the `DIV`s. I've just set it to `repeat` instead of `repeat-y`.

Comment: I think your answer is more accurate and relevant to my question. I needed the `absolute` and the `relative` because I didn't want to ruin the `<li>` dimensions by the `<a>` inside it and also place  the link text relative to the list elements, from your answer I constructed a better solution http://plnkr.co/edit/MFTcyNJ0x26kv6v1Nc7c?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3rUG7/3/)**

### Markup:

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div class="container">       
    <div class="sideBar">sideBar</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
*
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
html,body,.container, .sideBar, .content
{
    height: 100%;
}
h1
{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.container
{
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sideBar
{
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    background: aqua;
}
.content
{
    overflow:hidden;
    background: yellow;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to do the trick, I wander why all answers in forum give the background image trick