# how to reduce height on homepage (avoid excessive scroll)

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on a site and I'm kind of an advanced novice.  Can someone please tell me how to reduce the amount of space UNDER the footer? I can't seem to figure it out.
http://www.echoasylum.com/strong/category/artists/
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.css (line 98) you have `#sidebar{padding-bottom: 5000px;}`.
Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your css for sidebar:

```
padding-bottom: 5000px;
```

That means you should end up with the following:

```
#sidebar {
    background-color: #333333;
    width:225px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    color:#999999;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    /* margin-bottom: -5000px; */
    /* padding-bottom: 5000px; */


    right: 0px;
}
```

That in mind, I am assuiming what you were looking to do here is stretch the left bar all the way to the bottom of the page. I believe that this ([Full height sidebar and full height content, fluid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354018/full-height-sidebar-and-full-height-content-fluid-layout)) should help. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Drew!! This was SUPER helpful and fixed the problem. Many many thanks!