# Content div Not 100% height and width

Tags: html, css

I have two panels, one is the side bar and is 100% height and 100px width (purple), I also have in this some buttons (orange), then I have the right panel that has a top div that is 100% width and 100px height (green), this panel contains 3 buttons that float right (gray).

Now below this top panel I have a content div that is supposed to be 100% of remaining width and 100% of remaining height (yellow) however when you add more sidebar buttons (orange ones) the yellow panel inserts a white border at the bottom and if you resize browser's window also horizontally it inserts a blank border on the right, this white space is the body, but am having  a hard time trying to make content (yellow) panel fit the remaining width and height.

Quick example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g088H.jpg

Here is the working example I have so far: [Demo](http://www.sysarmor.com/dev/ISSUE)

```css
html {height: 100%;}

body {height: 100%; margin: 0px;}

#container
{
 background-color: #f00;
 height: 100%;
}

#sidebar
{
 background-color: #F0F; /*#E82E11*/
 width: 100px;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 100px; 
}

#rightcontent
{
 background-color: #00f;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-left: 100px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#topcontent
{
 background-color: #0f0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 min-width: 380px;
}

#content
{
 background-color: #ff0;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 380px;
}

.sidebaroptions
{
background-color: #FF2100;
border: 0px solid #F00;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
}

.sidebaroptions:hover
{
 background-color: #F50000;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebaroptionsselected
{
 background-color: #F50000;
}

.topoptions

{
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #3C3C3C;
    color: #FFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}

.topoptions:hover {
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions sidebaroptionsselected">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 <div class="sidebaroptions">new</div>
 </div><!--End of SideBar-->
 
 <div id="rightcontent">
  <div id="topcontent">
   <div class="topoptions">Config</div>
   <div class="topoptions">Config</div>
   <div class="topoptions">Config</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
   Bottom Content
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: I already fixed the problem width the right white space by adding min-width to content div (yellow), however I am still having a hard time width the bottom space, I´ll really appreciate if anyone could hepl me with this.

Comment: Same as above, post your code

Comment: You probably looking for something like this answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354018/full-height-sidebar-and-full-height-content-fluid-layout

Comment: I'm very confused. Your description does not match the image or any of the examples you have provided. The snippet gives a completely different result, too.

Comment: In the future, try to post the html and css together.  I combined them and see the yellow div, but it reaches the bottom in my version.  Please let me know which browser you're on or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Hello! Sure am using the latest firefox and the problem appears when you resize browser window like 300x300 when the scroll bars appear then the white borders appear, I would recommend to check on the website link and sorry for not posting code and css together this is my first post and controls are quite confusing.

Comment: Thanks Clyff, I can get the sidebar and the content bar working fine but when I add the top bar it gives the problem with the white borders I think it has something to do with top bar but can't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try **removing** the from your body style the `height:100%` and add to your content element an element with a clear:both applied to it like this:

```
<div id="content">
            Bottom Content
    <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Leo Farmer, I tried that but didn't work, I also updated the code since I was missing the #container and #sidebar. I also have to mention that I am using boilerplate.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried what Leo Farmer indicated there about removing the height 100% from body and it Worked!!. Thanks a lot to everyone who provided an answer to this. I really appreciate all of them!.

Comment: UPDATE: I got this working with the previous code Leo Farmer Provided But if I remove some buttons from the left then the side bar and yellow area get shorter as seen here: http://www.sysarmor.com/dev/ISSUE.

Comment: It seems that I got it working now and here is is how I did it: I set the body and html min height to 400px (minimum to avoid a space at the bottom), then I changed #rightcontent bakground color to same color of side bar so the space below the sidebar when shorter would be the same so won't be noticed and if more buttons are added then there's no problem, so far it is working okay.

Comment: I put the full code of this layout in case anyone would like to download it and use it or modify/enhance it. http://www.sysarmor.com/dev/applayout.zip